# buenas tardes , me sale este error y no lo puedo solucionar tienes algún consejo? (TypeError: empleados.map is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

**hola soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación y me he encontrado con un error que me ha dejado varado por varios días, me sale el error a la hora de llamar el empleados.map me sale el error (TypeError: empleados.map is not a function).**

Código
[image: codigo]
[image: codigo]

Error
[image: Error]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que investigaste o trataste, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Me parece que tu api no te devuelve un array, es por eso el error que te da. ¿Puedes mostrar el resultado de `console.log(datosRespuesta)`?

Comment: todo funcionaba perfecto hasta que agregue la funcion empleados:[]

Comment: Prueba cambiando `empleados: datosRespuesta` por `empleados: datosRespuesta.list`  en la función `cargarDatos()`y debe funcionar.

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') sale eso con el .list

Comment: Copia tu código como snippet (con texto) para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta de tu api es un objeto y los objetos no tienen el método map.La información que requieres viene en la propiedad `list` del objeto y sí es un arreglo. Lo único que necesitas hacer es cambiar `empleados: datosRespuesta` por `empleados: datosRespuesta.list` en la función cargarDatos().

Te adjunto un snippet de tu código funcionando al 100% que puedes ejecutar desde acá. Lo único que hice fue agregar `.list` :

```js
class Listar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            datosCargados:false,
            empleados:[]
        }
    }
    cargarDatos (){
    fetch("https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?channel=sport&limit=10")
    .then(respuesta=>respuesta.json())
    .then((datosRespuesta)=>{
        this.setState({datosCargados:true, empleados:datosRespuesta.list})
    
    })
    .catch(console.log)

    }

    componentDidMount(){
    this.cargarDatos();

    }
    render(){
        const{datosCargados, empleados}=this.state

        if(!datosCargados){return(<div>Cargando...</div>);}
        else{
        return (<table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Correo</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
a              <tbody>
                {empleados.map(
                   (empleado)=>(
                    <tr key={empleado.id}>
                    <td>{empleado.id}</td>
                    <td>{empleado.title}</td>
                    <td>{empleado.channel}</td>
                    <td>
                        <div className="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="">
                            <ReactRouterDOM.Link className="btn btn-warning" to={"/editar"}>Modificar</ReactRouterDOM.Link>
                            <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                )

                )}

            </tbody>
        </table>);
        }
    }
}
 
ReactDOM.render((
  <ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
  <Listar/>
  </ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter>
),document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
 <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom@5.0.0/umd/react-router-dom.min.js'></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```